# Как передать элементы списка в другой метод и там распечатать?

Tags: java

Мне необходимо передать list в другой метод и вывести на консоль по команде.

```
public void initArray3() {




    System.out.println("Введите число:");
    int num = 0;
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {

        num = scanner.nextInt();




        for (int i = 3; i <= num; i += 3) {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(i);




           System.out.println(list.iterator().next());


        }


    }





}
```

Comment: Вариант объявить List<Integer> list; в переменных класса где этот метод находится, а потом уже через list = new ArrayList<>(); инициализировать внутри метода не подходит?

При таком варианте этот лист можно будет использовать во всех методах класса.

Comment: Вы имеете виду так  list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(i);

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду код внутри метода то да.

Comment: Мне необходимо передать в другой класс. Если его вызвать в другом методе класса о уже  пустой .

Comment: Тогда добавьте в класс еще геттер который будет выдавать этот лист.
 Должен кстати отметить что создание ArrayList у вас находится в цикле. Т.е. вы каждый раз создаете новый объект. Дабы избежать этого нужно вынести из цикла инициализацию list

Comment: Это мини консольное приложение создание нового объекта думаю не страшно. Это не для продакшена.

Comment: В результате работы этого кода в ArrayList будет добавляться всего одно значение (то что в добавлено в него в той же итерации когда его и создали) и с началом новой итерации он станет недоступен для получения и уйдет к сборщику мусора.
Может вами так задумано, конечно, но уточню на всякий

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное !!!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Это ответило на ваши вопросы?

Comment: да, я понял в чом проблема.

Comment: Сейчас оформлю как ответ. Примите его, чтобы другие потом в случае подобной проблемы легко его нашли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо `List<Integer> list` объявить в переменной класса где у вас описан этот метод. Переменные объявленные внутри методов могут использоваться только внутри них.
А внутри метода уже инициализировать эту ссылку: `list = new ArrayList<>();`

Так же инициализацию нужно вынести за пределы цикла `for` чтобы избежать создания нового объекта при каждой итерации и добиться записи в `list` всех данных.

Для передачи же этого ArrayList в другие классы достаточно добавить в класс геттер возвращающий его.